# Moving text files one by one using batch-file with a timeout

Tags: batch-file

hi guys i'm a trying to move text files one by one with a timeout of 8 seconds from one folder to another using a batch script. i have this script so far;

```
move /-y "D:\example\original\*2007*.txt" "D:\example\New folder\"
```

what should i add so that it doesn't move the files at once?

Comment: you need user confirmation?

Comment: Are you looking for a prompt similar to `xcopy /P` (prompt before creation of each destination file)? you will have to write that on your own as `move` does not support such a `/P` switch...

Answer (score 0):

As **@npocmaka** recommend to you the user confirmation for example like this batch script : [Movies wrapper script](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133555/movies-wrapper-script/135148#135148)

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 

SET "ROOT=%~dp0"
SET "FORCE=0"

IF /I "%~1"=="/f" (
    SET "FORCE=1"
    SHIFT
)

IF "%~1"=="" GOTO :END_PARSE
SET "ROOT=%ROOT%%~1\"
:END_PARSE

ECHO -----------------------------------------------
ECHO WRAPPER - "%ROOT%"
ECHO -----------------------------------------------

SET "COUNT_SUCC=0"
SET "COUNT_FAIL=0"
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
REM Iterates throw the files on this current folder.
FOR %%f IN ("%ROOT%\*.*") DO (

    REM Checks if the file isn't the batch file.
    IF NOT "%%~ff" == "%~f0" ( 

        IF !FORCE! NEQ 1 (
        rem echo force=!Force!
            SET /P "INPUT=Do you want to wrap the file "%%~nxf" ? (Y/[N])"
            IF /I "!INPUT!"=="Y" (

                REM Create a directory as the same name.
                IF NOT EXIST "!ROOT!\%%~nf\" MD "!ROOT!%%~nf\">NUL 2>NUL

                REM Checks if the directory was created.
                REM /Y Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwirte an existing destination file.
                IF EXIST "!ROOT!%%~nf\" MOVE /y "%%~ff" "!ROOT!%%~nf\">NUL 2>NUL

                REM Count files who has been wrapped or not.
                ECHO.
                IF NOT EXIST "!ROOT!%%~nf\%%~nf%%~xf" (
                    RMDIR /s /q "!ROOT!\%%~nf\" >NUL 2>NUL
                    SET /a "COUNT_FAIL+=1"
                    ECHO The file "%%~nf" hasn't been wrap.
                ) ELSE (
                    ECHO The file "%%~nf" has been wrapped.
                    SET /a "COUNT_SUCC+=1"
                )
            )
        ) Else (
         REM Checks if the file isn't the batch file.
            IF NOT "%%~ff" == "%~f0" (
         REM Create a directory as the same name.
                IF NOT EXIST "!ROOT!\%%~nf\" MD "!ROOT!%%~nf\"
                rem >NUL 2>NUL

                REM Checks if the directory was created.
                REM /Y Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwirte an existing destination file.
                IF EXIST "!ROOT!%%~nf\"  MOVE /y "%%~ff" "!ROOT!%%~nf\"
                rem >NUL 2>NUL

                REM Count files who has been wrapped or not.
                ECHO.
                IF NOT EXIST "!ROOT!%%~nf\%%~nf%%~xf" (
                    RMDIR /s /q "!ROOT!\%%~nf\" >NUL 2>NUL
                    SET /a "COUNT_FAIL+=1"
                    ECHO The file "%%~nf" hasn't been wrap.
                ) ELSE (
                    ECHO The file "%%~nf" has been wrapped.
                    SET /a "COUNT_SUCC+=1"
                )
            )   
        )
    ) 
)
ECHO.
SET /a "COUNT_TOT=COUNT_SUCC+COUNT_FAIL"
ECHO Total of %COUNT_TOT% files(s) : %COUNT_SUCC% file(s) wrapped and %COUNT_FAIL% file(s) failed.
ECHO.
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

use a simple `for` loop to process each file individually:

```
for %%a in ("D:\example\original\*2007*.txt") do (
  move /-y "%%~fa" "D:\example\New folder\"
  timeout /t 8
)
```

For more information, see `for /?`